# How to convert Illumina IDs to Gene Names?

Tags: rna-seq, gene-expression

I am new to the area of bioinformatics, so apologies if this is too obvious of a query.

I need to analyze the RNA Seq data from [GSE98455](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE98455).

The dataset is of the following format:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|    Some Id          |      Counts      | 
|---------------------|------------------|
|    13101.t00001     |       392        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    13101.t00002     |        20        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I would like to extract the counts for certain genes only. So how do I match the ID column with gene names? Is there a reference table or something I need to look at?

Side Note: Usually for microarray data, I refer to the GPL files which provide a reference between accession ID and Gene Names. I was not able to do that for this RNA Seq Data set.

Update May 2, 2020: I reached out to the authors earlier today. I looked at the paper associated with this dataset, it seems the annotation belongs to *Oryza sativa japonica* reference genome v 6. I can't find anything related to it on the web. If I get any response from the authors, I will update it here.

Comment: you have to ask the authors. I checked https://plants.ensembl.org/Oryza_sativa/Info/Index?db=core and the gffs don't have any transcripts that match it

Comment: This is not illumina IDs. you can read the data processing, https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSM2596386, they aligned it to the ensembl genome and i have no idea what annotation is used